# Only the first word of the text is sent

Tags: python, discord.py

I wrote this code to send emails with a discord bot:

```
@client.command()
async def enviar_email(ctx, subject, to, content):
        #Create of E-mail
    msg = EmailMessage()
    msg['Subject'] = subject #Subject of E-mail
    msg['To'] = to #To whom will you send
    msg['From'] = EMAIL_ADDRESS #The email address you will use. You already changed it at the beginning of the code, don't mess with anything here.
    msg.set_content(content) #Content of E-mail

    with smtplib.SMTP_SSL('smtp.gmail.com', 465) as smtp:
        smtp.login(EMAIL_ADDRESS, EMAIL_PASSWORD)
        smtp.send_message(msg)
        await ctx.send(f'Enviado. \n \n Destinatário: {to} \n Assunto: {subject} \n Conteúdo: {content}')
        print(content)
```

However, the email body only shows the first word, not the entire content; and if I put more than one word in the subject, it fails and doesn't send. What is wrong with the code? How do I fix it?

Comment: Why do you re-assign your variables, e.g. `subject = msg['Subject'] = subject`? That should just be `msg['Subject'] = subject`, you don't need to assign to `subject` again.

Comment: I added a [tag:discord.py] tag since it looked like your question is about Discord. Please note that code _snippets_ are for HTML/CSS/JS. Use regular code blocks (or code fences) for other languages. Please also refrain from uploading [images of text](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551). Add it as [properly formatted text](/help/formatting)

Comment: What does `print(content)` show?

Comment: How are you sending the discord command? Do you quote the subject and content if they contain multiple words?

Comment: You should be able to easily debug this without touching discord, by the way...

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. "if I put more than one word in the subject, it fails and doesn't send" - well, think about how the interface to the code works. What will be the value of `subject` and `to` that are passed to the function, if you type multiple words for the subject? When the Discord framework calls your function, *how is it supposed to know* where the subject ends, and the email address begins?

Comment: @OneCricketeer no, the problem is caused by how Discord calls the function.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel As written "the email body only shows the first word", which is from `smtp.send_message()` call. None of the Discord code seems relevant to me given that `enviar_email()` call is not shown.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel If this is how discord calls the function, how can I solve this?